# og:description warning

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, tumblr

I have just tried to connect my [programming joke blog](http://thejoysofcode.tumblr.com) to Facebook via the OpenGraph API. However when I check using the developer debug tool, it gives a warning:

```
Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'fb:description'
```

and

```
The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given property being mismatched. Here are the input properties that were not seen in the parsed result: 'fb:description'
```

If I inversely remove this property, it tells me I should explicitly define it. Is this warning going to cause me problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<meta property="fb:description" content="For all those people who know what C is but can still remember what fun is">`

Should be

`<meta property="og:description" content="For all those people who know what C is but can still remember what fun is">`

The key part being `og:description`